Compatibility Issues with Ext JS 4.0 and Sencha Touch 2.0 in iOS 18.2 Beta – Legacy JavaScript Support and Rendering Problems
I am encountering compatibility issues with older JavaScript frameworks, specifically Ext JS 4.0 and Sencha Touch 2.0, after upgrading to iOS 18.2 Beta. My application, which was working fine on previous versions of iOS, is now experiencing rendering issues, broken touch events, and performance degradation on WebKit in iOS 18.2.
The issues I’m seeing include:
Sencha Touch 2.0: The UI elements (like fields, and lists) are not interactive or showing their content properly. There also seems to be a delay in rendering touch events.
This seem to no longer work as expected with the updated WebKit engine in iOS 18.2 Beta.
My Questions:
Are there any known issues with legacy JavaScript frameworks like Ext JS 4.0 and Sencha Touch 2.0 on iOS 18.2 Beta? Specifically, do these frameworks rely on older DOM methods or JavaScript features that might be deprecated in the latest WebKit engine?
Has Apple officially deprecated any JavaScript features or DOM methods in WebKit that might be causing these issues? If so, are there recommended workarounds or updates to ensure compatibility with iOS 18.2?
Is there a way to enable legacy JavaScript features or fallback modes in iOS 18.2 ?
I would appreciate any guidance on this, as we are facing significant issues with our app’s performance and UI since upgrading to iOS 18.2.
Thank you
Rakesh

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I tried running the app on previous iOS versions, and the UI and touch events worked as expected without any rendering issues.
I reviewed the WebKit release notes for iOS 18.2 Beta to see if there were any changes that might affect JavaScript DOM APIs or touch event handling. However, I didn't find any references to deprecated features affecting my framework directly.
I looked for any updates for Sencha Touch 2.0 or Ext JS 4.0 that might have compatibility fixes for iOS 18.2, but these frameworks haven’t received updates for a long time.

Ensure you are using Sencha CMD in the latest version.
If you use an older version of Sencha CMD the lastest updates for iOS won't be used while building.
Usually they use Sencha CMD to keep index.html and alike up to date.
Cheers

Since both Extjs 4.x and Sencha Touch are no longer supported, there wouldn't be any fixes from Sencha.
You could see if there are any polyfills available from apple or generally for legacy js features.
I'd check the dev tab in Safari and see what 'information' items you get in the console - that could lead you to clues of depreciated features.
